# apache start permision to user?

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, 18.04, php

Read list of errors are facing for **apache-start**

```
root@siddhant-VirtualBox:/home/siddhant# systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-07-11 17:06:57 IST; 36s ago
  Process: 26248 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26675 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21162 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox apachectl[26675]: apache2: Syntax error on line 151 of /etc/apache2
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox apachectl[26675]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox apachectl[26675]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited st
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 11 17:06:57 siddhant-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: *"Syntax error on line 151 of /etc/apache2"* is pretty specific - did you look there?

Comment: thanks for response and suggestion error for no MPM is not being loaded or working where do i get MPM file and how may i initialize my MPM file

Comment: hi. what is correct syntax for line 151 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my host without errors after i enable and install MPM file and then restart apache.

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
service apache2 restart
```